# How to use ADDDATE function in mysql while creating a view?

Tags: mysql, view

```
    CREATE VIEW USER_VIEW AS
    (
    SELECT USERS.ID ID,
   USERS.EMAIL EMAIL,
   USERS.PASSWORD PASSWORD,
   ADDDATE(USERS.START_DATE, INTERVAL USERS.DURATION MONTH) "EXPIRY_DATE",
   DATEDIFF(EXPIRY_DATE, NOW()) "STATUS");
```

Mysql is generating this error msg:

## 1109 - Unknown table 'USERS' in field list

Comment: Your query is missing a `from` clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would write this as:

```
CREATE VIEW USER_VIEW AS
    SELECT u.ID, u.EMAIL, u.PASSWORD,
           DATE_ADD(u.START_DATE, INTERVAL u.DURATION MONTH) as EXPIRY_DATE,
           DATEDIFF(DATE_ADD(u.START_DATE, INTERVAL u.DURATION MONTH), CURDATE()) as status
    FROM users u;
```

Notes:

- You need a `FROM` clause.  That is the big error in your query.
- Presumably, `EXPIRY_DATE` for `status` refers to the expression in the previous row.  This is not allowed.  You have to repeat the expression.
- There is no need to repeat column aliases.  When you choose `u.id` the column name is called `id`.
- Don't use single quotes for column aliases.  Choose names that do not need escaping.  If you do have to escape the names, then use backticks.
- I don't see why the time component would be interesting for "status", so I changed `NOW()` to `CURDATE()`.